downloaded weka 3.8.6 on arch linux, but when trying to start the gui i get an error saying Invocation.Target.Exception how could i solve this?
when starting up the gui i get the following error:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(Unknown Source)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1675)
4 more

and in the terminal i get:

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final >java.lang.Class >java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

i tried disabling the security manager but got weka error:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no/uib/cipr/matrix/Matrix
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.forName(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:198)
at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.forName(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:178)
at weka.core.ClassDiscovery.find(ClassDiscovery.java:247)
at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.generateOutputProperties(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:542)
at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:639)
at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:167)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.refreshGOEProperties(WekaPackageManager.java:1504)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1429)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1305)
at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.determineClasses(GenericObjectEditor.java:172)
at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.(GenericObjectEditor.java:242)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.(GUIChooserApp.java:707)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.createSingleton(GUIChooserApp.java:175)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1729)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: no.uib.cipr.matrix.Matrix
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 21 more

or when i try java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -jar weka.jar i get the same original error message but get this in the terminal too:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Failed to invoke main method
weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:319)
weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)


   at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:319)
   at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)



What version of Java? Java 21 onwards tightens up on this sort of reflected access.

Yes, it should work with Java 8 through to 17.
